# Lost WiFi after install of 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, ralink

**Once again** after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 the Wifi won't connect. I have both RaLink and Realtek adapters and usually Ubuntu won't connect to the Realtek adapter after an upgrade. This time, it won't connect no matter which adapter I'm using. It's confusing because if I boot into Ubuntu instead of Mate desktop, it shows I'm connected, but there's no internet. Doing a Ping in Term doesn't go anywhere, it just shows a blinking cursor and never pings, though it's showing the address I wanted it to ping.

It is very disheartening that upgrading doesn't auto connect to the previous working (21.10) wifi adapter and setup.

I'm using (gag) M$ Win11 now but need this to be working with 22.04.

How do I restore wifi in 22.04 now?

Thanks for any help. Note I have to close down, then bounce between Ubuntu and Win11 to run any tests, then reboot and come back to Win11 (separate HDD but same hardware otherwise) in order to communicate here so it'll take time to answer any questions.

**EDIT:** I found while messing around, that although 22.04 would never connect via WiFi, it will connect via an OpenWRT router using Cat5. So I don't have to bounce between Win11 & Ubuntu. Also found that Brave won't connect to the internet but Firefox will.

**EDIT #2:** Huh. Well, this morning I find that it WILL connect via Wifi but only with Firefox. Brave is blocked somehow with error code 159, so I'll research that for now. Guess it wasn't much of a problem afterall.

**EDIT #3:** Reinstalled Brave and it's now working fine. There were a couple times when I did an 'sudo apt update' in Term and that seemed to do the trick to bring back Wifi.

Thanks for the help. Next upgrade of Ubuntu, I'll try to be more patient.

Comment: You're dual-booting with Windows... Have you disabled its Fast Startup feature? A must when dual-booting. Start by doing that followed by a shutdown. Then, if the problem persists, please edit the question and identify the adapters.

Comment: The reflexive "*(gag) M$*" Windows-hate seems both unnecessary and distracting.

Comment: you don't indicate exactly what you have tried but perhaps [this reference](https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/) from it's FOSS might help.

Comment: 1) The problem isn't about dual booting, but about Wifi not connecting to the internet in Ubuntu when it did perfectly well before upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04. 2) I come by my hate for Windoze honestly after being a computer consultant for 16 years. 3) If there's some test, let me hear how it's done please. I did try connecting all 3 of my adapters, I would see them in the drop down list, I'd try to open Brave and I'd get nothing. I'd ping a web site, and nothing. Link is too old. But now I've found that if I connect to my OpenWRT router with Cat5, I can get online. Still need Wifi.